# Get data from SQL data base without refreshing use Ajax and node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

How to get data from SQL database without refreshing using Ajax with xmlrequest or fetch method, When I insert data or update it from SQL table how i can see this change without refresh or press any button

Please I need exemple with node JS server and EJS client page to resolve this problem

Comment: You can use polling or websockets, so search for some examples.

Comment: Yo are basically looking for web-sockets. You can also achieve this using long-polling. You can [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet) about them

Comment: depending on how important it is for your application to always have the latest data right when the SQL-database changes, it might just be sufficient to to make a request in a fixed interval. AJAX should never refresh your page, if that's what you mean.